# How can I show dialog on UI thread from another

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dialog

I'm using Show.Dialog on multiple threads, but there is a problem.
When the dialog box called from the UI thread is closed,
the MainWindow is activated even when there still are some dialog boxes called from another thread.
In order to avoid this, I'd like to show dialog boxes on the UI thread from another, but how is it possible?
Or is there any other way for me to avoid this problem?

```
public partial class CustomMsgBox : Window
{
    //this class implements a method that automatically
    //closes the window of CustomMsgBox after the designated time collapsed

    public CustomMsgBox(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        //several necessary operations...
    }

    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        var customMsgBox = new CustomMsgBox(message);
        customMsgBox.ShowDialog();
    }
}

public class MessageDisplay
{
    //on UI thread
    public delegate void MsgEventHandler(string message);
    private event MsgEventHandler MsgEvent = message => CustomMsgBox.Show(message);

    private void showMsg()
    {
        string message = "some message"
        Dispatcher.Invoke(MsgEvent, new object[] { message });
    }
}

public class ErrorMonitor
{
    //on another thread (monitoring errors)
    public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(string error);
    private event ErrorEventHandler ErrorEvent = error => CustomMsgBox.Show(error);
    private List<string> _errorsList = new List<string>();

    private void showErrorMsg()
    {
        foreach (var error in _errorsList)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ErrorEvent, new object[] { error });
        }
    }
}
```

When the CustomMsgBox called from the UI thread is automatically closed,
the MainWindow is activated even when there still are some CustomMsgBoxes called from the monitoring thread.

Answer (score 4):

You should only open the Dialog from the UI thread. You can invoke the UI-Thread with the dispatcher:

```
// call this instead of showing the dialog direct int the thread
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
{
    // Here you can show your dialiog
});
```

You can simpliy write your own `ShowDialog / Show` method, and then call the dispatcher.

I hope i understood your question correct.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the lack of information I first gave, but the 2 methods showMsg() and showErrorMsg() exist in the different classes. How can I get my MainWindow in the ErrorMonitor class, in which error monitoring methods are periodically executed in a different thread. When I tried Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, there happened an exception with the message "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I got an error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'Dispatcher'".

Comment: I made my ErrorMonitor class inherit Window, and this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke normally worked. However,when the dialog box called from the MessageDisplay class is closed, the MainWindow is activated even when there still are some dialog boxes called from the ErrorMonitor class. I'd like it not to be activated.

Comment: What is if you work with Topmost: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: I set the topmost of MainWindow to false, but it didn't give rise to any changes. When there is any dialog box, all the controls in the MainWindow should be unselectable.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. According to your instructions, I rearranged my problems and posted a new qustion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668524/c-sharp-a-trouble-regarding-window-showdialog