# C# A trouble regarding Window.ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

I have my custom message box class, which inherits Window class and has a method to automatically close itself after the designated time collapsed. I'm in trouble with the ShowDialog method of this class when I'm in a case described below.

1. There emerges a ShowDialog of a custom message box, which is set to automatically close in several seconds.
2. Before the first one is closed, there emerges a ShowDialog of another custom message box, which is not set to automatically close.
3. When the first one is closed, the ShowDialog function of the second one becomes invalid, ie. the MainWindow becomes selectable.

This problem happens no matter whether each custom message box emerges from a single thread or not.

How can I avoid this? If it is necessary to override ShowDialog, how is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need so many message boxes?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx): `When a modal WPF window (a window opened by calling ShowDialog) is closed, the previously activated window is reactivated. If a modal WPF window has an owner window (see Owner), the owner window is not reactivated when the modal WPF window is closed unless it was the previously activated window.`

Comment: @Eric One is for checking I/O from textboxes in the MainWindow, and the other is for monitoring errors in the background.

Comment: In all the threads, Owner is set to System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.

Comment: Why dont you move the error reporting from the main window to the background? That way they will be synchronized

Comment: @Eric I'm sorry but that seems impossible. In the project I'm in charge of now, there are some textboxes set on the MainWindow and I/O from them have to be checked by the MainWindow.

Comment: @icebat What does the word "previously" exactly mean in this case? If it means "before the modal window is shown", I'm unable to avoid my trouble, since it is the direct result of the normal function defined by ShowDialog. But if it means "before the modal window is closed", I'm able to avoid my problem by correctly designating the Owner property of each message box.